# Getting a calc() CSS variable into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, variables

I am trying to get a CSS variable into Javascript. I have read the other Stack threads pertinent to this goal, but I am still lost. Please save me from myself.

CSS:

```
:root {
     --loaderSpeed: 100ms; 
     --loaderDuration: calc(var(--loaderSpeed)*44);
    }
```

JavaScript

```
setTimeout(() => {
    const box = document.getElementById('loaderWrapper');
    box.style.display = 'none';
 }, 4400);
```

"4400" needs to be replaced with the variable --loaderDuration

Research indicates that these two are involved:

```
getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
    .getPropertyValue('--my-variable-name');
```

...but I have not been able to successfully implement.

Any ideas, Team? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Problem was, you are access root values which returns string.
- and `calc()` function cannot calculate multiplication of 100ms * 44 so, I have changed `--loaderSpeed:100` **removed `ms`**. and also created new valiable called `loaderSecondsMultiplier`.
- After that, I have `getPropertyValue` get css variables values and converted them into a number and then just mutiply them and in last store it in `finalTimeout`.

```js
//GETTING DOCUMENT STYLES
let docStyle = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement);
// GEETING CSS VARIABLE VALUES
let loaderSpeed = parseInt(docStyle.getPropertyValue('--loaderSpeed'));
let loaderSecondsMultiplier = parseInt(docStyle.getPropertyValue('--loaderSecondsMultiplier'));
// MUTIPLYING AND STORING IT'S VALUE TO finalTimeout
let finalTimeout = loaderSpeed * loaderSecondsMultiplier;
setTimeout(() => {
  const box = document.getElementById('loaderWrapper');
  box.style.display = 'none';
}, finalTimeout);
```

```css
:root {
  --loaderSpeed: 100;
  --loaderSecondsMultiplier: 44;
}
```

```html
<div id="loaderWrapper">
  <h1>hey</h1>
</div>
```

**Second approach**

```js
let docStyle = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement);

//get variable
let loaderDuration = docStyle.getPropertyValue('--loaderDuration');
loaderDuration = loaderDuration.split("ms*");
loaderSpeed = parseInt(loaderDuration[0].split("( ")[1]);
console.log(loaderSpeed);
loaderwheelSpeed = parseInt(loaderDuration[1]);

let value = document.getElementById("value");
value.innerHTML = `loader Speed: ${loaderSpeed} and loader wheelSpeed: ${loaderwheelSpeed}`

setTimeout(() => {
  const box = document.getElementById('loaderWrapper');
  box.style.display = 'none';
}, loaderSpeed * loaderwheelSpeed);
```

```css
:root {
  --loaderSpeed: 1000ms;
  --loaderDuration: calc(var(--loaderSpeed)*5);
}
```

```html
<div id="loaderWrapper">we are using string split method to extract correct value</div>
<p id="value"></p>
```

Comment: I edited to correct the typo, but I also removed the uppercase SHOUTING because, well, eww. That is my personal preference, which I probably shouldn't inflict on you, by all means do feel free to edit the uppercase back in.

Comment: Ahh, you beat me to it! though you have explained your answer much better so I think yours deserves to be accepted for future readers.

Comment: Not to mention, you made `loaderSecondsMultiplier` which makes the code more dynamic.

Comment: @DavidThomas I just thought to emphasize content, I should use Uppercase, however Its fine after all I respect my seniors and I know if they modified it then it will definitely for good.

Comment: @Nikkkshit You smashed it! Thank you very much.

Comment: ....and thank you David and Stranger. Very much appreciated. Go team!

Answer (score 0):

:) You are close enough, here's the correct way:

```js
let root = document.querySelector(':root');
let cs = getComputedStyle(root);
let loaderSpeed = cs.getPropertyValue('--loaderSpeed');
let loaderSpeedToInt = loaderSpeed.match(/\d+/);
let loaderDuration = loaderSpeedToInt[0] * 44;
setTimeout(() => {
  const box = document.getElementById('loaderWrapper');
  box.style.display = 'none';
}, loaderDuration);

console.log(loaderDuration);
```

```css
:root {
  --loaderSpeed: 100ms;
  --loaderDuration: calc(var(--loaderSpeed)*44);
}
```

```html
<div id="loaderWrapper"></div>
```

Comment: "*`4400` needs to be replaced with the variable `--loaderDuration`*" - OP is trying to retrieve the result of the `calc()` expression, to find the computed value of `--loaderDuration`; the approach you've posted here will - unfortunately - retrieve the string from the property `calc(var(--loaderSpeed)*44)` and not - again, unfortunately - the computed/calculated value.

Comment: @DavidThomas My bad, had a problem with reading, let me fix the var.

Comment: no worries at all.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks. Just fixed, alright now?

Comment: Having edited your answer to create a runnable snippet, I have to say "no," as I noted in my comment this will only ever return the literal string of the property: `calc(var(--loaderSpeed)*44)`.

Comment: @DavidThomas Now I get it, okay, I'll re-edit my code to include that. Can you tell me how you make it a runnable snippet?

Comment: To make snippets, see this question over on Meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you, I have edited it, is it all good now?